# How do I correctly plot?

Tags: plotting

Plot x^2/e^x for x in [-5,5]. Use PlotRange-> Automatic. The input that I came up with is Plot[{x^2/e^x},{x,-5,5},PlotRange->Automatic] A graph appears but there are no points.

Comment: `e` should be `E`. Mathematica is case-sensitive.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: You specify an interval, but no points. If you want points, you have to specify them. E.g.: Plot[..., Epilog->Point[{pont1, point2,..}]